# downloading 'boot.img' while using fastboot to copy ra recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

In the process of attempting to get Cyanogen MOD onto my HTC Hero. I rooted it successfully, and can connect with ADB.

I restarted the phone with the back key held down and get the fastboot screen.  I press volume down to get to the HBoot screen (otherwise fastboot was failing to connect).

Now I run:

> C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>fastboot boot recovery-RA-hero-v1.7.0.1.img

and get

> downloading 'boot.img'...

and I wait.   And wait.  And wait.  It certainly appears to be doing something in Task Manager (win 7) - it's showing some CPU activity, but how long is this step supposed to take? The longest I've waited was 1100 seconds before interrupting.

Using HTC Hero GSM.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're trying to boot the recovery image directly instead of flashing it onto your device?

Comment: At the time I was going through yet another poorly written walkthrough.  Some reading and understanding, and found it would make more sense to flash the image (clearly), and then the CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time I was semi-blindly following another poorly written walkthrough that just had a series of commands without explaining them.  Now with some knowledge I eventually worked out that it was better to flash the image to the phone.  Still don't know why it was taking so long though.

Eventually with flashing to the phone and then the Cyanogen Mod, I got it all working.  Now with ROMManager on my phone it'll be sooo much easier in future!